# Un-smoothing/scaling (help normalizing data)

Tags: normalization, bioinformatics

The context of this is matching experimental RNA SHAPE data to theoretical models of base pairing probabilities. RNA folds back on itself, some bases pair with each other, and some bases remain unpaired, making loops. SHAPE data gives "reactivity" of a base (proportional to *not* being paired) as a function of base index.

The data coming out looks something like this:

`qplot(x = 1:110, y = wt, geom = "bar", stat = "identity") # wt is reactivity trace, x is base index, sequence is 110 long`

[image: Wildtype reactivities by index]

Unfortunately, this does not match up to our model of pairing probabilities at all, which look like this:

`qplot(x = 1:110, y = probs, geom = "bar", stat = "identity")`

[image]

My advisor has a theory that the reactivity of a base not only depends on the base's probability of pairing, but also of its neighbors, and the type of nucleotides for all 3. I proposed a model that was like so: $$ p(i) \approx \alpha*react(i) + \beta*(react(i+1) + react(i-1))$$ Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the parameters that are estimated by fitting them to several datasets. My advisor didn't seem to like that method because it would probably end up smoothing the dataset even more. Is there a known way to "unsmooth" this data?

Comment: Perhaps the fear of "smoothing" is partly caused by conflating the model "$p(i) \approx \alpha \text{react}(i) + \beta (\text{react}(i+1) + \text{react}(i-1))$" with what would happen if you used "$\alpha \text{react}(i) + \beta (\text{react}(i+1) + \text{react}(i-1))$" as a *filter* to estimate $p$. The model describes how you think the probability of pairing actually works - if that model is a reasonable description of the process, it would be expected to describe what happens!  Fitted probabilities will be smoother than the reactivities, no doubt, but it's not a *problem*, it's the model.